# Sonarqube & Roselyn analysers configuration

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube

I try to configure a whole dev environment with pipelines on AzureDevOps and SonarQube as a static code analyzer.

I added several Roselyn Analyser (StyleCop for instance) and expected to see the issues on SonarQube. Some of them do appear but some don't.

For instance: SA1600 never show up on Sonar.
I added an .editorconfig file which works fine as i can switch off some issues. But whatever the parameter is for the SA1600, it does not appear.

This is quite uncumfortable as my devs would not have the same issues in VS and on Sonar.
How is it possible to configure Sonar to have the same configuration as it is in Visual Studio.
Any idea is welcome :)